# Implementing Producer/Consumer Communication

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, buffer, producer-consumer

I am attempting to implement producer/consumer communication through a bounded buffer using semaphores and locks I've already implemented in C. I need to have the producer place "hello world" onto a 5-byte buffer, one character at a time. The producer needs to block if the buffer is full. I am struggling to figure out how to place the string on the buffer. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 5

// the buffer works like a stack for
// the sake of simplicity, if needed
// we may implement a queue
 typedef struct {
    int buf[BUF_SIZE]; // the buffer
    size_t len; // number of items in the buffer
    pthread_mutex_t mutex; // needed to add/remove data from the buffer
    pthread_cond_t can_produce; // signaled when items are removed
    pthread_cond_t can_consume; // signaled when items are added
 } buffer_t;

// produce random numbers
void* producer(void *arg) {
    buffer_t *buffer = (buffer_t*)arg;

while(1) {
 #ifdef UNDERFLOW
    // used to show that if the producer is somewhat "slow"
    // the consumer will not fail (i.e. it'll just wait
    // for new items to consume)
    sleep(rand() % 3);
 #endif

    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer->mutex);

    if(buffer->len == BUF_SIZE) { // full
        // wait until some elements are consumed
        pthread_cond_wait(&buffer->can_produce, &buffer->mutex);
    }

    // in real life it may be some data fetched from
    // sensors, the web, or just some I/O
    int t = rand();
    printf("Produced: %d\n", t);

    // append data to the buffer
    buffer->buf[buffer->len] = t;
    ++buffer->len;

    // signal the fact that new items may be consumed
    pthread_cond_signal(&buffer->can_consume);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer->mutex);
}

// never reached
return NULL;
}

// consume random numbers
void* consumer(void *arg) {
buffer_t *buffer = (buffer_t*)arg;

while(1) {
#ifdef OVERFLOW
    // show that the buffer won't overflow if the consumer
    // is slow (i.e. the producer will wait)
    sleep(rand() % 3);
 #endif
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer->mutex);

    if(buffer->len == 0) { // empty
        // wait for new items to be appended to the buffer
        pthread_cond_wait(&buffer->can_consume, &buffer->mutex);
    }

    // grab data
    --buffer->len;
    printf("Consumed: %d\n", buffer->buf[buffer->len]);

    // signal the fact that new items may be produced
    pthread_cond_signal(&buffer->can_produce);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer->mutex);
}

// never reached
return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
buffer_t buffer = {
    .len = 0,
    .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    .can_produce = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,
    .can_consume = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER
};

pthread_t prod, cons;
pthread_create(&prod, NULL, producer, (void*)&buffer);
pthread_create(&cons, NULL, consumer, (void*)&buffer);

pthread_join(prod, NULL); // will wait forever
pthread_join(cons, NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good.  You could just have the consumer eat from buffer[0] and then memmove any remaining bytes like so: memmove(buffer->buf, buffer->buf + 1, sizeof(int) * buffer->len);  Also, you typically want to change your if (!condition_true)'s to a while (!condition_true)'s to handle signal interruptions and when you have more threads, which is common.

Answer (score 0):

a stack is a Last in, First out.  Not what you want.

I would strongly implementing a circular buffer, with a head and tail pointer.

Then use the mutex (no need for a semaphore) to lock the critical code.

(the critical code for the producer is where it is adding/trying to add a char)

(the critical code for the consumer is where it is removing/trying to remove a char)

the mutex is so the two critical variables 'head' and 'tail' are stable
while any one process is accessing the circular queue.